# key error and MultiIndex lexsort depth

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set of tab delimited files that I have to go through read them, use them as pandas dataframe, do a whole bunch of operations on them and then merge them back to one excel file, the code is too long so I am going to go through the problematic part of it

The tab files that I am parsing contains all the same number of rows 2177

When I read these files I am indexing by the first 2 columns of type (string, int)

```
df = df.set_index(['id', 'coord'])
data = OrderedDict()
#data will contain all the information I am writing to excel
data[filename_id] = df
```

one of the procedures I am doing needs access to each row of data[sample_id] which contains dataframe of mixed types indexed with the columns 'id' and 'coord', like this

```
sample_row = data[sample].ix[index]
```

my index being ('id','coord')

If I am treating a subset of the file everything works great, but If I read the entire files with 2177 lines I end up having this error message

```
KeyError: 'Key length (2) was greater than MultiIndex lexsort depth (0)'
```

I searched over SO and everywhere and it seems that this is an issue of sorting the index, but I dont understand why using an unsorted subset do not cause the problem

Any idea on how I can get this sorted out ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Docs are quite good. If you work with multi-indexes it pays to read them thru (several times!), see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-need-for-sortedness-with-multiindex)

```
In [9]: df = DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape(-1,1),columns=['value'],index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1,2,3],['a','b','c']],names=['one','two']))

In [10]: df
Out[10]: 
         value
one two       
1   a        0
    b        1
    c        2
2   a        3
    b        4
    c        5
3   a        6
    b        7
    c        8

In [11]: df.index.lexsort_depth
Out[11]: 2

In [12]: df.sortlevel(level=1)
Out[12]: 
         value
one two       
1   a        0
2   a        3
3   a        6
1   b        1
2   b        4
3   b        7
1   c        2
2   c        5
3   c        8

In [13]: df.sortlevel(level=1).index.lexsort_depth
Out[13]: 0

In [9]: df = DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape(-1,1),columns=['value'],index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1,2,3],['a','b','c']],names=['one','two']))

In [10]: df
Out[10]: 
         value
one two       
1   a        0
    b        1
    c        2
2   a        3
    b        4
    c        5
3   a        6
    b        7
    c        8

In [11]: df.index.lexsort_depth
Out[11]: 2

In [12]: df.sortlevel(level=1)
Out[12]: 
         value
one two       
1   a        0
2   a        3
3   a        6
1   b        1
2   b        4
3   b        7
1   c        2
2   c        5
3   c        8

In [13]: df.sortlevel(level=1).index.lexsort_depth
Out[13]: 0
```

**Update**:

`sortlevel` will be deprecated so use `sort_index` i.e

```
df.sort_index(level=1)
```

Comment: Thank you Jeff, well I know that and I read the doc but the problem is that it is only happening for dataframe larger than 1000 rows which I find weird !

Comment: That link to that specific anchor to the docs doesn't work anymore, you could refer to [this one](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#slicing-with-labels) instead.

Comment: Although the link to pandas documentation works, the anchor is not found and the word "sorting" does not occur in the linked page.  However, there is a mention of sorting [in the advanced indexing page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#sorting-a-multiindex).  Would that be a more suitable page to link here nowadays?