# Removing/"Repairing" a multiindex in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a large dataframe, that I concat out of different dataframes.

It is built from timeseries of different datatypes and looks something like this:

```
location                       locname1                     locname2
region                          region1                      region1   
HZB                              314732                       309906   
LatLon                            xx;yy                        xx;yy 
1940-01-01                          NaN                          NaN   
1940-02-01                          NaN                          NaN   
1940-03-01                          NaN                          NaN   
1940-04-01                          NaN                          NaN   
1940-05-01                          NaN                          NaN
```

But some of the dataframes I start with also have a `datatype` row in their index, which seems to get lost, when I concat them.

This does obviously point towards me not really understanding pandas multiindex, and I admit, the fact that pandas treats indexes totally different from what I am used to and how I intuitively treat them totally confuses me, but my understanding seems be sufficient for what I need to do.

Mostly, that is. When I try to plot the whole dataframe, I end up with a `KeyError: 'Key length (5) was greater than MultiIndex lexsort depth (0)'`.

Now, looking for that error, I [find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24922867/key-error-and-multiindex-lexsort-depth) [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116739/what-exactly-is-the-lexsort-depth-of-a-multi-index-dataframe) "solutions", which all just affect my date column, but ignore the index rows.

So, besides finally trying to get my head around multiindex, is there a `df.get_rid_of_my_multiindex()` kind of thing, where I can simply remove my multiindex, or just replace it with `number       1          2         3  …` or something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one possible solution is [`droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html)s of `Multiindex` in columns:

```
print df
     location locname1 locname2
       region  region1  region1
          HZB   314732   309906
       LatLon    xx;yy    xx;yy
0  1940-01-01      NaN      NaN
1  1940-02-01      NaN      NaN
2  1940-03-01      NaN      NaN
3  1940-04-01      NaN      NaN
4  1940-05-01      NaN      NaN

df.columns = df.columns.droplevel([1,2,3])
print df
     location  locname1  locname2
0  1940-01-01       NaN       NaN
1  1940-02-01       NaN       NaN
2  1940-03-01       NaN       NaN
3  1940-04-01       NaN       NaN
4  1940-05-01       NaN       NaN
```

If you need only reset column names use [`shape`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shape.html) with `range`:

```
df.columns = range(df.shape[1])
print df
            0   1   2
0  1940-01-01 NaN NaN
1  1940-02-01 NaN NaN
2  1940-03-01 NaN NaN
3  1940-04-01 NaN NaN
4  1940-05-01 NaN NaN
```

Comment: And another one of those things where pandas has exactly the function I am looking for, but I just fail to find it…  And the `df.columns = df.columns.droplevel([1,2,3])` variant is especially nice, since this easily allows me to keep my `location`, which is a nice, unique identifier for the plot. Thank you!