# Assigning values to a multi-index pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

This is my multiindex dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
arrays=[['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B',
          'C','C','C','C','D','D','D','D','E','E','E','E'],[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]]
hier_index=list(zip(*arrays))
#hier_index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(hier_index)
hier_index
index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(hier_index,names=["Camera","position"])
df1=pd.DataFrame(np.zeros([3,20]),index=["x","y","z"], columns=index)
```

I also have two for loops:

```
for i in range(0,20):
    x=[]
    for j in range(0,4):
        x_r= an equaton
        x.append(x_r)
    print(x)
```

the output of four loops is 5 lists with 4 elements each list is associated with A, B,C,D,E respectively. e.g. [0,0.1,0.2,0.3] , [0,0.4,0.5,0.6], and so on.
I want to assign elements of each list to 1,2,3,4 sub columns for all columns A,B,C,D,E. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: hi, not sure if might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23108889/set-value-multiindex-pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you will need both `i` and `j` in the for loops for something so, I did not remove them.  You can use `enumerate` to iterate through the top level index (e.g. A, B, C,...) and still keep the numeric index `i`.  With this you can simply assign `x` to a slice of your data frame using `loc`.  The loop below assigns your `x` (created with the equation `20*I+j`) to the slice, `df1.loc['x', (c,1):(c,4)] = x`, which specifies the row 'x' and the columns `(c,1):(c,4)` where `c` is one of your labels (e.g. A,B,C,...).

```
for i,c in enumerate(df1.columns.levels[0]):
    x=[]
    for j in range(0,4):
        x_r= 20*i+j
        x.append(x_r)
    df1.loc['x', (c,1):(c,4)] = x
    print(x)
```

Comment: Thank you Mathew, it is working on the data frame I put here. my actual data frame is very similar to this one, but when running there is an error.

Comment: df1.loc['b_h',(c,1):(c,4)]=b_h   UnsortedIndexError: 'Key length (2) was greater than MultiIndex lexsort depth (0)'

Comment: Mathew is there any way I can share with you my actual code?

Comment: Before sending code to and fro, have you checked out the following link, [key error and MultiIndex lexsort depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24922867/key-error-and-multiindex-lexsort-depth)?